# Searching files in $PATH

Tags: bash, files, path

I have some folders specified in my PATH environment variable. How do I list all the files in these folders?

Comment: Try a loop ... result might be lengthy.

Comment: `find ${PATH//:/ }`

Comment: What's do you need this for?

Comment: @IporSircer This should have been posted as the most KISS answer....

Comment: I agree. @IporSircer if you post this as an answer, I can mark your answer as the accepted answer :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this pipeline with any necessary modifications applied:

```
<<<"$PATH" sed 's/:/\n/g' | xargs -I@ find "@" -name '*a*'
```

Replace `-name '*a*'` with any filters you need. If you don't need to apply filters, etc, you can use the short version for the `xarg` part of the pipeline: `xargs find`, ie.:

```
<<<"$PATH" sed 's/:/\n/g' | xargs find
```

The `sed` part can in fact be reduced to a here string and delimiter definition as in:

```
<<<"$PATH" xargs -d: find
```